# How to play sound note (.mid file) on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, midi

I want to make piano player in which I want to play predefined notes which are some .mid files. Here is my code which is not working.

```
let soundPath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "0_100", ofType: "mid")
    let midiFile:URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: soundPath ?? "")
    var midiPlayer: AVMIDIPlayer?

    do {
        try midiPlayer = AVMIDIPlayer(contentsOf: midiFile, soundBankURL: nil)
        midiPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
        midiPlayer?.play {
            print("finished playing")
        }
    } catch {
        print("could not create MIDI player")
    }
```

Comment: how about defining the _sound-banks_ too? you can imagine MIDI like e.g. piece of paper with notes but the orchestra with intruments still needs to be defined for the concert.

Comment: you mean i have to set sound-banks too? i want to play note when user click button. every button play different notes

Answer (score 4):

`soundBankURL` is missing in the following:

```
try midiPlayer = AVMIDIPlayer(contentsOf: midiFile, soundBankURL: nil)
```

It's required according to the doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmidiplayer/1389225-init

> **Important**
>   For macOS the bankURL can be set to nil to use the default sound bank. However, iOS must always refer to a valid bank file.

A soundBank can be a .sf2 file for instance.

Comment: but i don't have soundbank file...i want to play note when user click on button.. different button generate different note sound

Comment: @sejalthesiya maybe try to find one on internet, like on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/soundbanks-135798.html or http://www.synthfont.com/links_to_soundfonts.html